# spring Data MongoDB , compare two fields in the same document

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following collection :

```
@Data
@Document(collection = "compte_titre_composition")
public class CompteTitreComposition {

  @Id private String id;

  @Field("numero_compte_titre")
  private String numeroCompte;

  private BigDecimal valorisationActuelle;

  @Field("date_valorisation")
  private Date dateValorisation;

  @Field("date_validite")
  private Date dateValidite;

}
```

and i want to select the elements which as a dateValorisation , and numeroCompte equal to the method params and **dateValorisation >= dateValidite** , so i wrote the following code :

```
  public List<EvolutionCompteTitreDto> getCpteTitreEvolution(
      String numeroCompte, LocalDateTime dateDebut, LocalDateTime dateFin) {

    List<AggregationOperation> listAggregations = new ArrayList<>();

    AggregationOperation matchByCpteAndDateValorisation =
        Aggregation.match(
            Criteria.where("numeroCompte")
                .is(numeroCompte)
                .and("dateValorisation")
                .gte("dateValidite")
                .gte(dateDebut)
                .lte(dateFin));
```

All condition works fine except this condition **dateValorisation >= dateValidite** (seems to not take it in concideration) the code does not take it into consideration

Comment: It is hard to simulate your situation locally, so forgive me. 1) Do you get errors or is your data just inconsistent? 2) Do you have unit-test that demonstrate this inconsistency and what happened to your matchByCpteAndDatValorisation when you ran it with debug? 3) Are the criteria of dateDebut and dateDebut applied to your query?    The only inconsistency I see is the possible mismatch between the Date and LocalDateTimes, however, you said the issue was only with dateValidate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is coming from the wrong comparison the method gte() takes as a parameter an object in order to compare it.In the case of comparing two fields in the same document we should create an expression like this :

```
AggregationOperation projetByValidDate =
    Aggregation.project(
            "dateValorisation",
            "dateValidite",
            "numeroCompte")
        .andExpression("dateValorisation - dateValidite")
        .as("duration");

AggregationOperation matchByCpteAndDateValorisation =
    Aggregation.match(
        Criteria.where("numeroCompte")
            .is(numeroCompte)
            .and("dateValorisation")
            .gte(dateDebut)
            .lte(dateFin)
            .and("duration")
            .gte(0));
```

Finally, this solution works for me